# RightView of UITextField don't have the same target

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield, rightview

I have a custom `UITextField` with a `rightView` containing a custom `UIView` with a draw rect (arrow) image. How can I get the `leftView` fire the same action as the `textfield`?

```
@implementation CustomDropDownTextField

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

        // Border Color of the UITextField - light gray
        self.delegate = self;
        self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.827 green: 0.827 blue: 0.827 alpha: 1] CGColor];;
        self.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

        self.rightView = [CustomDateDropDownArrowView default];
        self.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I have this custom textField with a custom `UIView` as the `righView`. I just want to fire `didBeginEditing` even if the user clicks on its `rightView`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is kind of vague, do you have any code your working with or screen shots of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Does anybody has a clue?

Comment: You can add a TapGestureRecognizer for your rightView and make textView to becomeFirstResponder in its handler. Need some code?

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out and see if I can manage to get it to work.